# Grafana Table Pivot rows into columns

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have this example data for a prometheus metric my_metric with labels:

```
customer="A", model="a", rev="1.0.13" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="A", model="ax", rev="2.1.8" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="B", model="a", rev="1.0.4" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="B", model="ax", rev="1.0.22" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="B", model="z", rev="2.0.5" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="C", model="a", rev="1.0.0" ----------- metric value: 1
customer="C", model="ax", rev="1.0.0" ----------- metric value: 1
```

I want to query it in Grafana and display it as a table showing:

```
Customer         a        ax       z
A                1.0.13   2.1.8 
B                1.0.4    1.0.22   2.0.5
C                1.0.0    1.0.0
```

I tried a simple PromQl query:

```
max(my_metric) by (customer, model, rev)
```

This gives me a table that looks like this:

```
customer   model    rev
A          a        1.0.13
A          ax       2.1.8    
B          a        1.0.4
B          ax       1.0.22 
B          z        2.0.5 
C          a        1.0.0
C          ax       1.0.0
```

But it seems like I'd need to do more Transform on it? - I just haven't figured it out yet. Any tips?